# Find density of $x_1.x_2.x_3$ from joint density of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ using transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, transformation

I need help in the following problem, I solved it but my answer is wrong 
(my final answer is different than that of the reference)

I think the limits of the integration are wrong, but I do not know what they should be!

Given the following joint density
$$f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{2}{2e-5}x_1^2x_2e^{x_1.x_2.x_3}$$
$$0<x_1,x_2,x_3<1$$

It is required to get the distribution of 
$$x_1.x_2.x_3$$
I used the transformation 
$$z=x_1.x_2.x_3$$
$$u=x_1$$
$$v=x_2$$
Hence the inverse functions are
$$x_1=u$$
$$x_2=v$$
$$x_3=\frac{z}{uv}$$
I differentiated the inverse functions and got the Jacobian
$$|J|=\frac{1}{uv}$$
Hence
$$f_{u,v,z}=\frac{2}{2e-5}ue^z$$
where 
$$0<u,v<1$$
$$0<z<uv$$
To get the required distribution, the distribution of z, I integrated the above function w.r.t u and v .
$$f_z=\int_{v=0}^{v=1}\int_{u=0}^{u=1}f_{u,v,z}dudv=\frac{e^z}{2e-5}$$
$$0<z<1$$
However the final answer in the reference is
$$f_z=\frac{1}{2e-5}(1-z)^2e^z$$
$$0<z<1$$

Comment: In your integration limits, you have not taken account of the inequality $0 < z < uv$. Suppose you integrate $u$ first, the dummy variable inside the inner integral. Then make $u$ to be the "subject", we have $u > z/v > 0$. Therefore combining with $0 < u < 1$, we should have $z/v < u < 1$ as the integration limit. Once $u$ is integrated out, you consider $z = x_1x_2x_3 < x_2 = v$, and therefore we should have $z < v < 1$ as your integration limits of the outer integral, and we will get the desired result.